Ansible EDA Kafka Connection Error - trying to create a connection to kafka within a rulebook but the rulebook activation fails
I have been trying to create a connection to kafka within a rulebook but when I run my rulebook activation I experience this error:
ansible_rulebook.rule_set_runner - INFO - Ruleset: Listen for events, received shutdown: Shutdown(message="Shutting down source: ansible.eda.kafka error : KafkaConnectionError: Unable to bootstrap
Rulebook:
- name: Listen for events
  hosts: 127.0.0.1

  sources:
    - ansible.eda.kafka:
        host: kafka.broker.com
        port: 9092
        topic: my_topic_name
        groupId: my_group_id
        securityProtocol: SSL
        ssl_certfile: "/tmp/tls.crt"
        ssl_keyfile: "/tmp/tls.key"
        ssl_cafile: "/tmp/ca.crt"
        sslEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm: https

Is my syntax correct or should I use different key words to pass the certs?
I have tried multiple keywords for the certificates and was expecting for rulebook activation to be running.

It seems to be security_protocol instead of securityProtocol and it's recommended to use SASL_PLAINTEXT instead of SSL, with sasl_mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
